# "Tommy the boy" or "the boy Tommy"?

Tags: phrase-usage, word-order

I noticed that one would not always write "the boy Tommy", sometimes "Tommy the boy" is written instead.

My questions are:

1. Are they equivalent? That is to say, are they interchangeable everywhere?
2. If not, then would you please provide some counterexamples?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of how they are used? I don't use either very often, though neither is necessarily incorrect; it might also be *Tommy, the boy* or *the boy, Tommy* or *boy Tommy* or *Tommy as a boy* in various situations.

Comment: Is it a brand? A film? What? Explanation needed. Or you want to ask ***The [something]*** and ***[something] the [something]***?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily the first term will be one which has already been introduced into your discourse, and the second will provide a more specific identification.

- *The boy Tommy* identifies *Tommy* as the particular boy you are talking about: *this* boy rather than *that* boy.

  > Mrs. Kowalski identified the boy Tommy as the one who had stolen her handbag.
  >   The boy Tommy has been located, but Jimmy is still missing.
- *Tommy the boy* identifies *the boy* as the particular Tommy you are talking about: Tommy the boy rather than Tommy the girl, or young Tommy rather than grown-up Tommy.

  > Tommy the boy is rather stupid, but Tommy the girl is a math prodigy.
  >   Tommy the boy was always in trouble; but now he is Chief Justice of the Supreme Court.

Sometimes the second term is bracketed in commas or parentheses; this marks the identification as 'supplemental', additional information of secondary importance:

> The boy, Tommy, has brown hair and is about 4'10" tall.
>   Tommy, the boy, has been located, but his father Jimmy is still missing.

Comment: Agree with these as default interpretations, but it could depend on context/intonation. One could contrast "the *boy* Tommy" with "the *adult* Tommy" (same individual at different ages).

Comment: If I knew two Alex's of different genders, I might easily refer to them as "the boy Alex" and "the girl Alex" in casual speech.

Comment: "Tommy the Boy" could also be a title/nickname like "Billy the Kid". Although "The Boy Tommy" is also a possible nickname.